# counting total degrees of a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, pseudocode

In a directed graph, the total degree of a node is the number of edges going into it plus the number of edges going out of it. Give a linear-time algorithm that takes as input a directed graph (in adjacency list format, as always), and computes the total degree of every node. The output of the algorithm should be an array  total[.], with an entry for each node.

this is my pseudo-code for this problem:

```
procedure total degree(G)
Input: Directed graph G=(V,E)
Output: array total[.] with an entry for each node

for all u in V in[u]=0
for all u in V:    
    for all (u,v) in E:
        in[v]=in[v]+1

for all u in V out[u]=0
for all u in V:
    for all (u,v) in E:
        out[u]=out[u]+1 

for all u in V total[u]=0
for all u in V:
    total[u]=in[v]+out[u]
return total[u]
```

can someone concur i did this right or tell me what i need to fix if i made a mistake, what im really unsure about is if i did the outdegrees (out[.]) right

i used this code as a reference point to come up with my own:

```
function sources(G)
Input: Directed graph G = (V;E)
Output: A list of G's source nodes
for all u in V : in[u] = 0
for all u in V :
    for all edges (u,w) in E:
        in[w] = in[w] + 1
L = empty linked list
for all u in V :
    if in[u] is 0: add u to L
return L
```

Comment: there actually no inner for-loop its all just one loop, I just wrote it this way because that's how my book does it. let me try and explain the in[.] for-loop block of the pseudo-code. First the algorithm looks at all the nodes (|V|) which I represent as u, and assigns an array in[u] that counts all the in-degrees (all the directed edges going into the node). it goes through each edge starting at u and counts all the in-degrees that u has, for each u, since u is just a variable that represents a node

Answer (score 2):

Your second for block is the same as the first one, the only difference being the array name. This means it's going to count the same edges as the first one, giving you a wrong result.

In your second for, you need to count the other edge, not the same one:

```
for all u in V out[u]=0
for all u in V:
    for all (u,v) in E:
        out[v]=out[v]+1
```

---

Alternatively, you could count them all in one go:

Assuming input `G=(V,E)` is a list of nodes (`V`) and a list of edges (`E`) represented by node pairs (`(u, v)`), and assuming duplicates should count, all you need to do is count the nodes (both out and in) in the edge list.

```
for all u in V
    total[u] = 0

for all (u, v) in E
    total[u] = total[u] + 1
    total[v] = total[v] + 1

return total
```

Comment: to answer your earlier question,  
there's actually no inner for-loop its all just one loop, I just wrote it this way because that's how my book does it. let me try and explain the in[.] for-loop block of the pseudo-code. First the algorithm looks at all the nodes (|V|) which I represent as u, and assigns an array in[u] that counts all the in-degrees (all the directed edges going into the node). it goes through each edge starting at u and counts all the in-degrees that u has, for each u, since u is just a variable that represents a node

Comment: But then you do have inner for don't you? How can you count edges for each u, unless you use another loop inside that one?

Comment: i see your point and i added on to the code to make it a bit clearer, also this is just pseudo-code what i mean by this code is that first for each u i make an in[.] array, and then for all nodes u, i transverse this list and note the amount of edges going in or going out. the edge(u,w) just represents some arbitrary node u (since its a variable) and the node that comes right after it (w) that constitutes an edge (u,w). the for-loop for the edges part is just an extension of the for loop for each node u, its not a separate or an inner for-loop

Comment: Okay, I'm not certain on how you don't use another loop, but nevermind that. I updated the answer to give you a concrete answer to your question. In your out array, you need to use the other edge, not the same one. But the best I can suggest is to fire up your favorite programming language and just run it and see :)

Comment: i added code that's straight out of my solutions, which i also used as a reference for writing this code, as well as changed my code a bit to make it more correct

Comment: thanks, you were correct regarding that i needed to change my out or in to be different from the other (the first code block in your solutions)

Comment: Presumably you'd also want to switch the order of `(u,v)` to `(v,u)`?

Comment: @Manetheran  why should i switch order?

Comment: My understanding is that the ordering in the tuple is important. I.E `(u,v)` indicates `u --> v` in a directed network. So if you are looking at all nodes `u` in `V`, then `(u, v)` will only find the outgoing edges. To find the incoming edges you need to look at `(v,u)`, because this will give you all edges `v --> u`.

Comment: @Manetheran It's either to make the switch, or to use the other node, but I prefer the latter, since it keeps the edge marking consistent (u is the from node, v is the to node, and we choose which one to count). If we switched how we mark the pair, u would only represent the node we want to count.